# Cant figure out how to fix Error 1452

Tags: mysql

I cant figure out this error message.I know there are similar post but they have not helped.

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`workingmodel`.`cadet`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Cadet_YEAR_t1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`YEAR_t_idYEAR_t`) REFERENCES `year_t` (`idYEAR_t`) ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `workingmodel`.`cadet` (`CID`, `YEAR_t_idYEAR_t`, `Rank_idRank`, `BN_idBN`, `PTscore`, `Academic_idAcademic`, `CadetLastName`, `CadetFirstName`) VALUES ('00123456', '2015', 'CPL', '2', '220', 'CS', 'Matthews', 'Bob')
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've done so far to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is all about `Referential Integrity`.

Table `cadet` is dependent on table `year_t` on column `YEAR_t_idYEAR_t` into column `idYEAR_t`.

You are inserting a value `2015` on table `cadet` that the value of `YEAR_t_idYEAR_t` doesn't exist on table `year_t`.

To fix your problem, you need to insert `2015` on table `year_t` first and execute your `INSERT` statement again.